# how to set current transform as default status of an object in blender

Tags: axis

in blender, after make transform to an object, for example, rotate it 90 degree, then it has a rotate transform number there. how to set this number to 0 while still keep the above transform? that is, I want the object keep current transformed direction as its first/default direction.

Comment: You need to apply the rotation (Ctrl A), or rotate your mesh in Edit mode instead of rotating the object in Object mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just have to apply the current transformation of your object for that: `Object` -> `Apply` -> `All Transforms`

[image]